# Javascript Test value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a html table I an trying to create a function for. I will loop over all of the column names and if they contain a word that is in my array, I will turn that columns value into a formatted link accordingly.

```
function createLink(field, val){

    // Create a mapping of our data
    var output = {
        'ntid': 'https://example.com/profile/'+val,
        'email': 'mailTo:' + val
    };

    // Test and return values
    // pseudo code

    if(field matches a key partially in output){
        return '<a href="'+output[value]+'" target="_blank">'+[val]+'</a>';
    }else{
        return 'No Matches';
    }

}

 // Examples
 createLink('NTID', 'bob'); // '<a href="https://example.com/profile/bob" target="_blank">bob</a>';
 createLink('Sup NTID', 'bob'); // '<a href="https://example.com/profile/bob" target="_blank">bob</a>';
 createLink('Email', 'bob@example.com'); // '<a href="mailTo:bob@example.com" target="_blank">bob@example.com</a>';
 createLink('Sup Email', 'bob@example.com'); // '<a href="mailTo:bob@example.com" target="_blank">bob@example.com</a>';
```

How could I go about testing the value to see if it has a partial match in my `output` array and then returning its formatted link?

Since these column names are dynamic and could change any time, I just want to test for partial words rather than the exact string.

If there is no match, I could just return a placeholder value such as "No Match".

Comment: You could use indexOf to check if the value is in the object. Ex. if(output.indexOf(string) === -1)
{//No match}
else
{//Match}

NOTE. This will not work if you are checking with the key-values of your object.

Comment: @9focuspoints - This would tell me if its in there but how would I then would I access it directly in order to get the value?

Comment: Use regex with i flag new RegExp(valueToCheck.replace(/[.?*]/g,"\$1"), "i")

Comment: Post the real `output` array with some examples!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir - Updated the post with some examples

Comment: @SBB `output` is not an array! It's an object! Plus, what do want to match!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate `Object.keys` and return if a key is in the "field" string:

```js
function createLink(field, val) {

    var output = {
        'ntid': 'https://example.com/profile/' + val,
        'email': 'mailTo:' + val
    };

    for (var key of Object.keys(output))
        if (field.toLowerCase().includes(key))
            return `<a href="${output[key]}" target="_blank">${val}</a>`;

    return 'No Matches';
}

// Examples
console.log(createLink('NTID', 'bob'));
console.log(createLink('Sup Email', 'bob@example.com'));
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for Firefox but having issues with IE due to it not liking `key of` or `includes()`. Any chance you could show an example of an all around compatible version?